# Aggregating Data with MAX & GROUP BY in VIEWS with a WHERE restriction

Tags: t-sql

Here is my Request.
Our Application generates a statement which invokes a view in a SQL-Server DB.
This statement selects DISTINCT or GROUP BY Data-fields from the view 
passing a restricted subset of IDs.

### Background:

I am using SQL-Server 2008 R2 running on Windows Server 2008 R2 
With an example-table I will try to explain the problem.

Given this example table: [TabA]

```
ID [INT]    DATA [VARCHAR(8)]  
---         ----
51           A1 
50           A1 
110          A5
100          A5
```

---

We then create the following view:

```
CREATE VIEW ViewOnTabA
AS
 SELECT
   MAX(ta.ID) As ID, ta.DATA
 FROM 
   TabA ta
 GROUP BY ta.DATA
GO
```

---

With this statement, generated by our application, 
we call the view passing some ID values:

```
SELECT 
 ID, DATA
FROM ViewOnTabA  
WHERE ID in (51,50,110,100)
```

---

The result is Ok 
The Data fields are grouped and complete:

```
ID  DATA
--  ----
51  A1
110 A5
```

---

If instead of all IDs we pass only the smaller ID number: (50 instead of 51)
...

```
WHERE ID in (50,110,100)
```

The result is incomplete (ID 50 is missing):

```
ID  DATA
--  ----
110 A5
```

But we expected

```
ID  DATA
--  ----
50  A1
110 A5
```

It seems that in a VIEW the GROUP BY is executing before the WHERE condition.
As we cannot invoke stored procedures from our application, 
we have to rely on calling a view. 
Are there other possibilities to have a DISTINCT or GROUP BY order
of the DATA fields (in the example) within a VIEW.
The ID-fields must not necessarily be filtered with the MAX aggregate function.
But the Where restriction has to be applied on them.

### P.S.

Executing this Select in a normal query including 
the (`WHERE ID in` ...) restriction  it works fine:

```
 SELECT
   MAX(ta.ID) As ID, ta.DATA
 FROM 
   TabA ta
 WHERE ID in (50,110,100)
 GROUP BY ta.DATA
```

output>>>>

```
ID  DATA
--  ----
50  A1
110 A5
```

For simulating this example
here are the create & insert statements:

```
create table TabA 
(
ID  int ,
DATA varchar(8)
)
go

insert into TabA values (51,'A1')
insert into TabA values (50,'A1')
insert into TabA values (110,'A5')
insert into TabA values (100,'A5')
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Alberto

Answer (score 0):

For this to work the way that you are expecting to, you would need to remove the `group by` from your view.  The reason why you are not seeing for e.g. the "`50`" in your results, is because it is already filtered out by the `group by` in the view.

You will either need to change your view (if nothing else is using it), or create a new view like this:

```
CREATE VIEW ViewOnTabA  /* or use a new name */
AS
 SELECT ta.ID, ta.DATA
 FROM TabA ta
GO
```

... and then run the select statement with the where clause on this view.

```
SELECT
   MAX(ta.ID) As ID, ta.DATA
 FROM 
   ViewOnTabA ta  /* or use the new view's name */ 
 WHERE ta.ID in (50,110,100)
 GROUP BY ta.DATA
```

Comment: Our interactive application generates SQL-statements based on a
selection of "objects" done by users. The IDs of those objects are then
used in the WHERE ID IN (...) clause. 
To retrieve the SQL-DB-Data, the application allows only an access through
a TABLE or a VIEW

Example:
SELECT  ID, DATA FROM ViewOnTabA  WHERE ID in (50,110,100)
OR
SELECT  ID, DATA FROM TabA  WHERE ID in (50,110,100)

We need to get the values of DATA (A1, A5 in the example) in a DISTINCT order, 
regardless which ID comes along with. So I attempted to use aggregate functions
and GROUP BY in a VIEW to solve this request.

Comment: I'm afraid that (if I understand correctly), that won't help with your problem.  You would need to apply the aggregation at run time and not in a view.

Comment: Hi RoKa
Thank you for the effort in searching a solution.
We now try to solve this issue with a workaround in the application api.